# Powershell script - updating grid field in GUI from background job running ping test

Tags: powershell, automation

I will paste the code below but I am a super novice powershell scripter and I am trying to create a little ping test applet to learn about GUIs and scripting in powershell and also to explore the use of LLMs as a way to assist in code generation.  I have the thing mostly working but one thing I cant figure out is how to get the result of each ping test to show up in a status filed of a targets grid that exists in the GUI.  the intent is for the user to populate a small grid with info on targets to ping and then the script spawns a background job which continuously pings each target and logs the results.  all that is working but one thing I wanted to add was for a column in the targets grid named status to get updated with the result of the last ping test that ran for each target on an ongoing basis as long as the jobs are running.  I have the field get prepopulated with "N/A" before the jobs start and that works fine but then as the jobs start going that value never changes.  I know that the function where the ping test code lives is getting and updating the correct values to actually find the right row of the grid and the status to put there but the field itself still never changes.  I think the issue is with the background jobs not being able to reach back into the main thread that spawned the GUI and actually write to the field but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.  I would really appreciate it if anyone could take a look and give some advice on this!

here is the code. just a heads up there is a hard coded value here for the network interface I want to use to populate the information about the source side of the pings and if you dont change it to match your interface you will get an error but the script will still run you just wont get the source info on the GUI.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Define the GUI form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Ping Test"
$form.Width = 600
$form.Height = 500
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Define the form elements
$logLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$logLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$logLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$logLabel.Text = "Log file path:"
$form.Controls.Add($logLabel)

$logTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$logTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 30)
$logTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(430, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($logTextBox)

$browseButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$browseButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(450, 30)
$browseButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$browseButton.Text = "Browse..."
$form.Controls.Add($browseButton)

$sourceLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$sourceLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 60)
$sourceLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$sourceLabel.Text = "Source Info:"
$form.Controls.Add($sourceLabel)

$sourceTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$sourceTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 80)
$sourceTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 20)
$sourceTextBox.ReadOnly = $true
$hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$localIP = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 3" | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress
$publicIP = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.ipify.org?format=text")
$sourceTextBox.Text = "Hostname: $env:COMPUTERNAME Local IP: $localIP Public IP: $publicIP"
$form.Controls.Add($sourceTextBox)

$targetsLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$targetsLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 110)
$targetsLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$targetsLabel.Text = "Targets:"
$form.Controls.Add($targetsLabel)

$targetsDataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$targetsDataGridView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 130)
$targetsDataGridView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 200)
$targetsDataGridView.ColumnCount = 2
$targetsDataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Name"
$targetsDataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "IP Address"
$statusColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
$statusColumn.Name = "Status"
$targetsDataGridView.Columns.Add($statusColumn)
$form.Controls.Add($targetsDataGridView)

$intervalLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$intervalLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 340)
$intervalLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$intervalLabel.Text = "Interval (seconds):"
$form.Controls.Add($intervalLabel)

$intervalTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$intervalTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220, 340)
$intervalTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$intervalTextBox.Text = "5"
$form.Controls.Add($intervalTextBox)

$statusLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$statusLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 370)
$statusLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$statusLabel.Text = "Status:"
$form.Controls.Add($statusLabel)

# Define the start and stop buttons
$startButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$startButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 420)
$startButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$startButton.Text = "Start"
$form.Controls.Add($startButton)

$stopButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$stopButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120, 420)
$stopButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$stopButton.Text = "Stop"
$stopButton.Enabled = $false
$form.Controls.Add($stopButton)

# Define Instructions text box label
$instructionsLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$instructionsLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(370, 130)
$instructionsLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$instructionsLabel.Text = "Instructions:"
$form.Controls.Add($instructionsLabel)

# Define the instructions text box
$instructionsTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$instructionsTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(370, 150)
$instructionsTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(210, 100)
$instructionsTextBox.Multiline = $true
$instructionsTextBox.ReadOnly = $true
$instructionsTextBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$instructionsTextBox.Text = "1. Specify a csv log file (will be created if it doesn't exist)" + "`r`n" +
                            "2. Add targets to the grid (leave status box blank)" + "`r`n" +
                            "3. Set an interval for the pings" + "`r`n" +
                            "4. Click Start"
$form.Controls.Add($instructionsTextBox)

# Define the log file path
$logFilePath = ""

# Define the ping function
function Ping-Target {
    param($targetName, $targetIPAddress, $interval, $logFilePath, $localIP, $publicIP, $statusColumnIndex)

    $logHeader = "Timestamp,SourceName,SourceInternalIP,SourcePublicIP,TargetName,TargetIP,ReplyTime,Bytes,TTL,Status"

    # if the log file doesn't exist or is empty, write the header
    if (-not(Test-Path $logFilePath) -or (Get-Content $logFilePath).Count -eq 0) {
        $logHeader | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Encoding UTF8
    }

    while ($true) {
        $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $targetIPAddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $status = if ($pingResult -and $pingResult.ResponseTime -ge 0) { "Success" } else { "Failure" }
        $replyTime = if ($pingResult) { $pingResult.ResponseTime } else { "" }
        $bytes = if ($pingResult) { $pingResult.BufferSize } else { "" }
        $ttl = if ($pingResult) { $pingResult.TimeToLive } else { "" }
        $logLine = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}" -f (Get-Date -Format "ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), $env:COMPUTERNAME, $localIP, $publicIP, $targetName, $targetIPAddress, $replyTime, $bytes, $ttl, $status
        Add-Content $logFilePath -Value $logLine
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
            param($statusColumnIndex, $status, $targetIPAddress)
            $statusColumn = $targetsDataGridView.Rows | Where-Object { $_.Cells[1].Value -eq $targetIPAddress } | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Cells[$statusColumnIndex]
            $statusColumn.Value = $status
        } -ArgumentList $statusColumnIndex, $status, $targetIPAddress
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $interval
    }
}

# Define the event handlers
$browseButton.Add_Click({
    $logFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $logFileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    $logFileDialog.Title = "Select a log file"
    if ($logFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $logTextBox.Text = $logFileDialog.FileName
    }
})

$startButton.Add_Click({
    # validate log file input
    $logFilePath = $logTextBox.Text
    if ($logFilePath -eq "") {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a log file.", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        return
    }

    # create the log file if it doesn't exist
    if (!(Test-Path $logFilePath)) {
        try {
            $null = New-Item -Path $logFilePath -ItemType File -ErrorAction Stop
        } catch {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error creating log file: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
            return
        }
    }

    # validate interval input
$interval = $intervalTextBox.Text
if (-not [int]::TryParse($interval, [ref]$null) -or $interval -le 0) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please enter a positive whole number for the interval.", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    return
}

# Get the targets from the DataGridView and start a ping job for each target
$targets = @()
foreach ($row in $targetsDataGridView.Rows) {
    if ($row.Cells[0].Value -ne $null -and $row.Cells[1].Value -ne $null) {
        $targetName = $row.Cells[0].Value
        $targetIPAddress = $row.Cells[1].Value
        $status = $row.Cells[2].Value
        $targets += [pscustomobject] @{
            Name = $targetName
            IPAddress = $targetIPAddress
            Status = $status
        }
    }
}

# validate minimum targets
if ($targets.Count -eq 0) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please define at least one target to ping.", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    return
}

# Set the status label and disable the start button
$statusLabel.Text = "Status: Running"
$startButton.Enabled = $false
$stopButton.Enabled = $true

foreach ($target in $targets) {
    # Set the default status to "N/A" if it's not already set
    if ($target.Status -eq $null) {
        $row = $targetsDataGridView.Rows | Where-Object { $_.Cells[1].Value -eq $target.IPAddress }
        $row.Cells[2].Value = "N/A"
        $target.Status = "N/A"
    }

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:Ping-Target} -ArgumentList $target.Name, $target.IPAddress, $interval, $logFilePath, $localIP, $publicIP, $targets.IndexOf($target)
    if ($job.Error) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("An error occurred while starting the ping test job: $($job.Error[0].Exception.Message)", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Stopped"
        $startButton.Enabled = $true
        $stopButton.Enabled = $false
        break
        }
    }
})

$stopButton.Add_Click({
    Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force
    $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Stopped"
    $startButton.Enabled = $true
    $stopButton.Enabled = $false
})

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I have modified the function a few times to try to get it to be able to write back to the main thread when it gets called from the background jobs but i cant work it out.

Comment: Thats a nice chunk of code for a novice Powershell user!

Comment: I haven't actually ran your code, and haven't thoroughly tried to comprehend it or your description of it.  But as for threading issues, if you push a button, and the code in that button takes too long, it will freeze the form until the button's code is done.  If you try to update a form, or one of it's controls, from another thread, typically nothing happens.  Only the form's thread can update the form's control's content.  If you are wanting to ping every few seconds, there are 2 timer type objects that should both be able to update on form's thread.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks!  but most of it was generated by chatGPT at my pormpting.  its taken 35 versions to get it into this state but there is no way I would be able to make it from scratch

Comment: @Darin, thats a good point but I think the threads are running pretty well.  Part of the code is outputting to a log file and that part of the function seems to be working nicely no matter how long I let it run.  its just that the background jobs dont seem to be updating the GUI which was spawned by the main thread.  Im certain I am just syntactically doing something wrong which is the issue.  Also, I did have some debug code in there earlier which was inside the function that output the values Im intersted in to a csv file and that worked fine.  its just writing it to the GUI which fails.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but I'm wondering if `((Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Sort-Object -Property InterfaceIndex)[1] | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress` produces the same result for you as `(Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 3" | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress`.  My thought/theory is that when you sort `Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4` by `InterfaceIndex`, index 0 will be the 127.0.0.1 IP, and index 1 will be your main IP.  But I could be wrong, not sure yet.

Comment: @Darin thanks for taking the time to make a suggestion here.  I have been spending the time until I can get an answer on the field update question on fixing that exact issue.  I decided to add a drop down to the GUI which has the available network interfaces on the system.  you just pick the one  you want and the source info is filled out by querying that interface.  I dont think I have room in this comment to show the code but i will try it as another comment.

Comment: @Darin here is the code

# Define the network interface drop down
$interfaceLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$interfaceLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 110)
$interfaceLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$interfaceLabel.Text = "Network Interface:"
$form.Controls.Add($interfaceLabel)

$interfaceDropDown = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$interfaceDropDown.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 130)
$interfaceDropDown.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)

Comment: $interfaceDropDown.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList
$form.Controls.Add($interfaceDropDown)

$networkInterfaces = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | Where-Object { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Up' -and $_.SupportsMulticast }
foreach ($interface in $networkInterfaces) {
    $interfaceDropDown.Items.Add($interface.Name)
}
blicIP"
})

Comment: $interfaceDropDown.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $selectedInterface = $networkInterfaces[$interfaceDropDown.SelectedIndex]
    $localIP = $selectedInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses | Where-Object { $_.Address.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork" } | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address
    $publicIP = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.ipify.org?format=text")
    $sourceTextBox.Text = "Hostname: $env:COMPUTERNAME Local IP: $localIP Public IP: $publicIP"
})

Comment: I thought about a drop down, and that is a good idea.  But I just discovered that if, and this is an if, you know for sure your IP uses DHCP, then this will either reduce your list, or possibly get it down to one item: `Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -PrefixOrigin Dhcp`

Comment: @Darin hey that's not a bad idea and that would work fine on my test system but in production this applet would likely be running on a server or maybe a jumpbox which would likely have statically assigned configs.  as it is the list only populates with interfaces which are connected which pretty much keeps the list to a minimum.